# Get upload progress using Azure Storage Node.JS SDK

Tags: node.js, azure

Looking at [this](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-blob-storage/#how-to-upload-a-blob-into-a-container), we have some code that looks like

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');    
var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService()

blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('mycontainer', 'giantFile', 'giantFile.bak', function(error, result, response){
  if(!error){
    // file uploaded
  }
});
```

This "work" but we have no idea about the status of each upload until it returns. We'd like to print the progress of the upload to the console since it's a sequence of very large files that can take several hours.

Comment: have you found any way to show progress ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid i don't think its possible out of the box with the SDK. [MSDN Artical](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/cef82efe-5218-430d-9873-c661dd5358f0/how-to-check-upload-progress-when-using-azure-nodejs-sdk-createblockblobfromlocalfile?forum=windowsazuredata#343ab5f0-b30f-4be4-89fb-bebe30834542) Apparently such an API hasn't been implemented yet.